# Does the length of the text to be hashed affect the probability of a collision?

Tags: cryptography, sha1, hash-collision

I want to make unique code with sha1 with unique salt (definitely unique because i use id from table). I need unique code with 7 character but i can't use id from my table because it's more than 7 character. So i think it's better to use sha1 and take first 7 character of hashed text as my unique code. Does the length of the text to be hashed affect the probability of a collision?

for example :

```
textA = "myId:12345678"
textB = "myId:12345678, myId2:87654321"
```

Is it better to use long short text (e.g textA) or text (e.g textB)? Or does the text length have no effect?

Comment: Also see Kelsey's work on [Truncated Hashes](https://www.google.com/search?q=kelsey+truncated+hash). There is no reduction in proof that a truncated hash holds the same properties of a full hash. If possible, you should avoid the truncation. Maybe you can use [Format Preserving Encryption](https://www.google.com/search?q=Format+Preserving+Encryption). FPE has accompanying proofs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hashing your unique IDs is a bad idea. Don't do it.

If your IDs consist of 7 hex digits, that gives you 268,435,456 unique values to play with. If you hash these values and truncate the results to 7 hex digits, then [the probability of a collision rises very quickly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack) (1% probability after 2,322 inputs, 50% after 19,290 inputs, 99% after 35,159 inputs).

If your aim is to disguise these ID values so that an adversary is unable to figure out what the actual sequential values are, then use [format-preserving encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption) instead.

**Edit:** If you need something secure, you could try implementing a [Feistel network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher) using an encryption function like AES as the round function. (AES is overkill, perhaps, but this could be implemented in a few lines of code in most languages based on existing primitives.) If you just want to obfuscate the IDs, you could use something simpler like this:

```python
def obfuscate_id(id, key):
    # Transforms id using a 28-bit key
    a = 81883721   # (random prime congruent to 1 mod 4)
    c = 2791751    # (any odd number will do)
    m = 2**28      # (modulus for 7-digit hex values)
    return ((id ^ key) * a + c) % m
```

Comment: and jww thanks for your suggestion. I have read about format-preserving-encryption. Actually, i don't aim to disguise these ID values but i want to make random and unique code (7 or 8 string only). I think i can use these ID for unique code but my ID has to much character. So i need make it to 7 or 8 digits. If possible, let me know how i can do that. Thanks

Comment: @FerryGideon Sorry about the delay; I've updated the answer slightly.